# How to create a communication between browser and application

Tags: python, browser, udp, websocket, communication

I have a big problem, and I am having a hard time solving it. I have a custom made game controller, which outputs some data from it's sensors via serial communication and is connected to PC via serial port. I do the callculation of the current controller position in a Matlab script. I am building a web application that will display the data (position) of the device in a web browser, but can't seem to work out, how to connect my device to the browser. Matlab script sends all the position data to a UDP port with a sampling fequency of 100HZ (100 samples per second). I need to make a persistent connection between a web browser and my matlab script so I will be able to display the data. I am thinking about using web sockets API. but it does not "speak" UDP. So my idea was to somehow read the data with from UDP with a custom Python server and then create a websocket on that Python server and send data received via UDP port to web browser. Oh, and it would be nice if I could communicate in both directions. Will this work? Any ideas on how to do it? How is this usually done, I mean how can one connect let's say some temperature sensor to web browser to display data in real time?

Any answer will be gladly appreciated.

Thanks,
Leon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that although the WebSockets protocol is built on TCP sockets, the WebSockets protocol is not raw TCP sockets. A WebSockets connection has an HTTP friendly handshake (with some CORS functionality built-in). WebSockets are also message based (rather than streaming like TCP) so each message has a couple of bytes of framing headers.

You might look at [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) (disclaimer: I made websockify). Websockify is a python server that bridges/proxies between WebSockets and plain TCP sockets. I don't think it would be particularly difficult to adapt it to handle UDP sockets on the backend.

WebSockify (designed to be used together with the included include/websock.js front-end library) supports binary data even over the older Hixie versions of the protocol. This allows it to work with iOS (iPhone,iPad) devices which still only support the older version of the protocol.